# react js match rows with similar data

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, match

I am facing an issue in react js. I want to match row data according to column values.

my react component:

```
        <div className="row">
          {this.state.staff.map((data, i) => (
          <div className="full-block">
              <p key={i}>
              {data.full_name}
              </p>
              </div>
          )
          )}
        </div>
```

My output
[image]

Expected output[image]

working demo
https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-sara-3ebcq?file=/src/App.js

what should i do? what i change in my code?

Comment: Can you provide the expected output?

Comment: As well as a better explanation of what "match rows" means along with some sample input data as per [mcve]

Comment: i added a photo [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7595722/rodentman87)

Comment: can you write the some cod e[@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-sara-3ebcq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: i added an example you can check [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl)

Comment: Short answer is you need to map the data into the structure you want that would produce expected results

Comment: can write the some code plz? [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl)

Comment: No...this isn't a free code writing service